# GeoServer WMS is slow when using OpenLayers and OSM

Tags: postgis, geoserver, openlayers, openstreetmap, amazon-web-services

I am new to GIS, and attempting to create a map with **PostgreSQL/PostGIS**,**GeoServer**, **OpenLayers**, and **OSM data**.

I am only serving the NA continent, but it is taking approximately 20 seconds to render the entire map at zoom level 2 (with only roads, boundaries and land use attributes), which is too long for use.

My DB specs are as follows:

| Type | Provider | Version | RAM | VCPU | Storage | Storage Type | Prov. IOPS | Storage Throughput |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Postgresql | AWS RDS | 13.7 | 128GB | 16 | 2TB | gp3 SSD | 12,000 | 500 Mibps |

I have tuned the db to these specs:

| Shared Buffers | Work Mem | Main. Work Mem | AutoVac Work Mem | Checkpt Timeout | Max Wal Size | Checkpt Completion Target | Max Wal Senders | Random Page Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 125 MB | 3 GB | 10 GB | 2GB | 60 Min | 10GB | 0.9 | 5 | 1.0 |

There is only 1 user for this map service so far, and the DB CPU utilization never goes above *20%* . So, I don't think the DB is the problem, but please check my settings.

I have **GeoServer** running in a docker container on an **ECS** cluster, with a t3.2xlarge instance featuring *32.0 GB* RAM and *8 vCPU*. These are my configured GeoServer settings:

*DataStore*
[image]

*Server status*
[image]

*System Status*
[image]
[image]

GeoServer doesn't seem to be using much of its allocated CPU **or** RAM.

My frontend is a small cluster that runs this OpenLayers code:

```
        let extent: Ext.Extent
        let locations_layer: VectorLayer<VectorSource<Geometry>>
        if (location_list.length > 0) {
            console.log(bbox)
            extent = createExtentFromBoundingBox(JSON.parse(bbox))
            console.log(extent)
            const location_features = createLocationFeatures(JSON.parse(location_list));
            console.log(location_features)
            const locations_source = new VectorSource({ features: location_features });
            locations_layer = new VectorLayer({ source: locations_source });
        } else {
            extent = null

        }
        const view = new View({ center: [0, 0], zoom: 2 });


        const main_roads = new Tile({
            source: new TileWMS({
                url: 'http://3.129.23.222/geoserver/wms',
                params: { LAYERS: 'atlas-workspace:planet_osm_roads', TILED: true },
                serverType: 'geoserver',
                transition: 0
            })
        });

        const polygon = new Tile({
            source: new TileWMS({
                url: 'http://3.129.23.222/geoserver/wms',
                params: { LAYERS: 'atlas-workspace:planet_osm_polygon', TILED: true },
                serverType: 'geoserver',
                transition: 0
            })
        });

        const supporting_roads = new Tile({
            source: new TileWMS({
                url: 'http://3.129.23.222/geoserver/wms',
                params: { LAYERS: 'atlas-workspace:planet_osm_line', TILED: true },
                serverType: 'geoserver',
                transition: 0
            })
        });

        const points = new Tile({
            source: new TileWMS({
                url: 'http://3.129.23.222/geoserver/wms',
                params: { LAYERS: 'atlas-workspace:planet_osm_point', TILED: true },
                serverType: 'geoserver',
                transition: 0
            })
        });

        map = new Map({
            target: target,
            view: view,
            layers: [polygon, supporting_roads, main_roads, points]
        })

        view.fit(extent);
    });
```

You can also visit the service here: http://3.19.245.25:8080/

Comment: Try with https://docs.geoserver.org/2.22.x/en/user/geowebcache/using.html.

Comment: Are you using different geometries/layers at different zoom level? There is no need to work with millions of street segments (or polygons), so for larger zoom you can have simplified pre-unioned roads (geometries). Also for more complex polygons (like Water), you can try to `st_subdivide` them, but that would have more effect at smaller zoom levels

Comment: Just to double check, did you set shared_buffers = 125 _MB_ or 125 _GB_? 125MB would be claustrophobic. On a 128GB server doing nothing but PostgreSQL it should be 30-40GB, and can be less if the database size is small enough to fit.

Answer (score 0):

If all your WMS layers are from the same service it would be more efficient to combine them in a single OpenLayers source and layer:

```
    const wmsLayer = new Tile({
        source: new TileWMS({
            url: 'http://3.129.23.222/geoserver/wms',
            params: {
                LAYERS: [
                    'atlas-workspace:planet_osm_roads'
                    'atlas-workspace:planet_osm_polygon',
                    'atlas-workspace:planet_osm_line',
                    'atlas-workspace:planet_osm_point'
                ],
                TILED: true
            },
            serverType: 'geoserver',
            transition: 0
        })
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, this doesn't improve the performance.

Comment: Or try increasing the tile size to reduce the number of requests?  e.g. specify `tileGrid: createXYZ({tileSize: 512}),` in the source options

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the [WMS image format](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/outputformats.html) to reduce the size when loading them on OSM. Hopefully can help improve your performance

Comment: Tiling is usually more efficient as OpenLayers caches tiles client side, so less reloading when panning the map.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it really worked. I'm combining them together

Answer (score 0):

You don't say anything about how you imported the data, and whether you have pre-generalized version of the heaviest layers to be used for the smallest zoom levels.

Please check [this repository](https://github.com/geosolutions-it/osm-styles), it contains styling for OSM In GeoServer, and along with it, instructions on how to perform an import that is optimized for rendering, along with the usage of the pre-generalized data store.
That, along styles that render only a subset of the information at the smaller zoom levels, is used to support the generation of the slippy map you can find at geoserver.org

Comment: Thanks for this, but I don't see a link to the repo provided.